# How do I make an interface for clicking a value in column(of dataframe) and then selecting values by its group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, user-interface, tkinter

I have this huge database `Sentiments.csv` of 64296 entries.
[image]

I have used:

```
    df=pd.read_csv("Sentiment.csv")
    df1=pd.DataFrame(df["App"])
    df1["Sent"]=df["Sentiment"]
    df1["Reviews"]=df["Translated_Review"]
```

to put it into a data frame, which looks like below:
(The `Sent` column (It has 3 unique values `[Positive,Negative,Neutral]` which isn't visible here *check the above screenshot for reference*,There are 1074 unique `App` names, I couldn't display the whole dataframe  here for obvious reasons):

```
                               App  ...                                                 Reviews
0            10 Best Foods for You  ...  I like eat delicious food. That's I'm cooking ...
1            10 Best Foods for You  ...    This help eating healthy exercise regular basis
2            10 Best Foods for You  ...                                                NaN
3            10 Best Foods for You  ...         Works great especially going grocery store
4            10 Best Foods for You  ...                                       Best idea us
5            10 Best Foods for You  ...                                           Best way
6            10 Best Foods for You  ...                                            Amazing
7            10 Best Foods for You  ...                                                NaN
                           ...  ...                                                ...
64287  Houzz Interior Design Ideas  ...                                                NaN
64288  Houzz Interior Design Ideas  ...                                                NaN
64289  Houzz Interior Design Ideas  ...                                                NaN
64290  Houzz Interior Design Ideas  ...                                                NaN
64291  Houzz Interior Design Ideas  ...                                                NaN
64292  Houzz Interior Design Ideas  ...                                                NaN
64293  Houzz Interior Design Ideas  ...                                                NaN
64294  Houzz Interior Design Ideas  ...                                                NaN
```

I want to Generate an interface in **Tkinter** where we can see the respective reviews categorized as `Sentiments` - positive, negative and neutral after we have selected the `App`  from a list of apps in the same dataframe.

Since the number unique of apps is huge I couldn't even display the same number of labels and buttons for it check out my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59617786/tkinter-long-list-display-in-grid),
to which I can use groupby functions. I couldn't also figure out the groupby statement that I should use here. I was thinking of calling Pandas table everytime I select an app and then display its respective Reviews sentiment wise
eg:

```
____________________________________
|         |Positive|Negative|Neutral|
__________ ________ ________ _______
|Reviews__|good    |bad     |okay   |
             .        .        .
             .        .        .
             .        .        .
         
__________|________|________|_______|
```

I'm new to Python any help would be appreciable, I want to add this interface in my project.

Comment: doing all from scratch may need some work. Maybe see [pandastable](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable)

Comment: This looks pretty straight forward. All you need is a couple `ttk.Combobox` with values set to unique values of each column, query the dataframe using the selected values, and display it (perhaps using a `ttk.Treeview`).

Comment: Can you tell me the code for Grouping those values. I cant figure it out.

Comment: I had recently answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59644172/how-to-create-a-button-or-option-which-allows-a-user-to-filter-a-treeview-based/59646921#59646921). You can take a look and adapt to your needs.